# Map the compose key to the right click key in KDE Neon

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, compose-key

How can I map the compose key on my laptop keyboard to the right click key?

I am using KDE Neon.

Comment: Self-answered questions are generally welcomed, thank you! However, please be a little bit more careful to the correct spelling. Sentences start always with capital letter, and also "I" is always capital letter on English.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
-> Settings
-> Input devices
-> Keyboard
-> advanced
-> Position of compse key
-> Menu